# MYSQL Foreign Key Relationship between parent Child

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have created 2 tables with a parent child relationship in MYSQL. However, the foreign key relationship fails with error code 1215. The MAIN_ROLE can have many SUB_ROLE aliases. The SUB_ROLE has a composite PRIMARY key (ID,MAIN_ID,SEQ_NUM). The  MAIN_ROLE table's PRIMARY KEY is part of SUB_ROLES primary key. 
 Here are the tables and my constraints:

```
     create TABLE MAIN_ROLE(
      ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  MAIN_ID int NOT NULL,
  ASSIGNED_DATE datetime NULL,
  MAIN_ROLE_NM varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ID,MAIN_ID) 
     );


    create TABLE SUB_ROLE(
     ID int NOT NULL,
 MAIN_ID int NOT NULL,
 SEQ_NUM decimal(15, 0) NOT NULL,
 SUB_ROLE_NM varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(ID,MAIN_ID,SEQ_NUM) ,
 CONSTRAINT SUB_ROLE_FK REFERENCES MAIN_ROLE(ID,MAIN_ID,SEQ_NUM)
    );
```

Could someone point out what's wrong with the foreign key in my scripts? Please help!

Comment: You would be missing the seq_role column in the table main_role

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked, CONSTRAINT SUB_ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID,MAIN_ID) REFERENCES MAIN_ROLE(ID,MAIN_ID)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are not following mysql's [foreign key syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and that you a referencing a field in the parent table that is not there:

1. You do not provide a list of fields from the child table
2. `SEQ_NUM` field does not exist in the main table, only in the sub table.

Correct foreign key definition would look like as follows:

```
CONSTRAINT SUB_ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID,MAIN_ID) REFERENCES MAIN_ROLE(ID,MAIN_ID)
```

However, I do not really see ehat's the point of having an auto increment id field and a main_id field in the main table. I would take a 2nd look at that.

Comment: I did not design the table unfortunately, so I have no control over it.

Comment: Pls be a bit more specific as to what exactly you have tried and what error message / unexpected behaviour you encountered. Not to mention the fact that I linked in the relevant manual page for MySQL, so if there is some minor syntax / spelling error in the actual code I suggested, then you can resolve them on your own.

Comment: I solved it by providing this statement instead: CONSTRAINT SUB_ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID,MAIN_ID) REFERENCES MAIN_ROLE(ID,MAIN_ID)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input

Comment: So, I missed the `FOREIGN KEY` from the statement. This is why you should have provided the exact error message, not just simply that it did not work...

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Many thanks for your assistance